# 2 Python scripts use the same GPIO pin RPI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Is it possible to write 2 scripts

1 For setting a GPIO pin

and 1 for reading out what the status of the gpio pin is.

I now have written these two scripts in python. but when I launch them both only 1 will work

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.IN)
print GPIO.input(18)
```

The other one listens to a button and if the button is pressed the pin 18 is set to high, if he is pressed again the pin is set to low

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pushbutton = 2
relay = 18

GPIO.setup(pushbutton, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)

def main():
    ingedrukt = GPIO.input(pushbutton)
    try:
        while (True):
            if(ingedrukt == False):
                if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) == False):
                    sleep(0.5)
                    if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) ==False):
                        GPIO.output(relay, GPIO.HIGH)
                        ingedrukt = True
                        print "Pushed"
            else:
                if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) == True):
                    GPIO.output(relay, GPIO.LOW)
                    ingedrukt = False
                    print "Not pushed"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Quit"
        GPIO.cleanup()
main()
```

Is this possible anyway if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the relay as a GPIO input to read the state. All you need is the print GPIO.input(18) command. So your first script should read:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
print GPIO.input(18)
```

I would add the line

```
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
```

Comment: does this mean the one script would be able to read from the GPIO pin while the main script is interacting with the GPIO pin?  I'm not OP, I'm just clarifying as I have had the need to do this as well.

Comment: Yes, tested it on my pi. As long as the second scrip is running the first can grab the pin state. The key is not to define the pin as an input.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concurrently run two scripts? Why not have the print statement in your listening script? Also, your printing status of the pin script needs a while loop

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I want to run this script when ever I want to run it. and the script with the pushbutton needs to run all the time. So I can run the status script from a webserver so I can check what the status is at the moment. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean only one works? Maybe this helps?

> It is possible that you have more than one script/circuit on the GPIO
>   of your Raspberry Pi. As a result of this, if RPi.GPIO detects that a
>   pin has been configured to something other than the default (input),
>   you get a warning when you try to configure a script. To disable these
>   warnings:
>       `GPIO.setwarnings(False)`

from: http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

Comment: yes I know but then you just don't get the warning but it still don't work